# Java visual vm profiler saying class sharing enabled when it's off

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, visualvm

I'm trying to do some memory profiling on a java application launched from eclipse. Even though I set the run configuration options -> VM arguments -Xshare:off I am still getting the visual vm error where it says class sharing is enabled for this JVM and it won't display any information. You can even see in the overview tab it says -Xshare:off.

When I build my application into a jar file for deployment and run the visual vm on it I am able to profile. So I believe it has something to do with eclipse but I have no idea what.

I also added -Xshare:off to the eclipse ini file to make sure it was launching without class sharing but that made no difference.

Any ideas? Everything on the web I've found so far with this error just says to disabled class sharing with -Xshare:off.

[image: http://i46.photobucket.com/albums/f107/markmahle/visualvm1_zps146877fa.jpg]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My co-worker figured out the issue. I was launching eclipse as admin, but not launching the visual vm as admin. Once I launched the visual vm as admin as well I was able to profile.